# MongoDB object size insertion issue C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

My problem is we are trying to insert a document into MongoDB and it seems to exceed the size limit of 16 MB. Now, we can debug and see what aggregates to the complete object itself but I don't know a way to see what part of the nested document amounts to the large file size in C#.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

/Per

Comment: This does not anwser your question but, If you know that your document will be "large" then don't use MongoDB to store it. Store object data as a system file and in mongo store file location that can be requested separately.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores all data as JSON documents. And 16MB limit is counted as a trimmed JSON file without unnecessary indentation.

To get the same result parse your object to JSON using MongoDB serializer or use an external one like Json.NET.

Then inspect this JSON document or do some computation on it to know how many characters are in each part of the document and act accordingly to your architecture to reduce this document to below the limit or...

...don't use MongoDB to store it. Store object data as a system file and in mongo store file location that can be requested separately.